# Add more elements to a HTML-form that is posted to a php-script

Tags: forms

I am working on a script where the user can write information in a HTML-form that will be downloadable in a pdf-file.

Some of the users might want to add more information than others (e.g. several names), because of this I want to add the functionality to add more textboxes that will send the information to the PHP script.
[image]

What is the best method of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

i'm doing it with jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/ or http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

you just insert a piece of html with some variable setted by the jquery(name/id/ etc)

Comment: How can I use this if the users are pressing a button?

Comment: you just have to use this insert code (with a var setted by html content) on the "onClick()" event of the button